# Full Screen AlertDialog changes the layout color

Tags: java, android

I'm using the code from another answer here:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Dialog d = adb.setView(new View(this)).create();
    // (That new View is just there to have something inside the dialog that can grow big enough to cover the whole screen.)

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    d.show();
    d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

I really find it usefl to make an alertDialog full screen, but the colors end up being a black background with white text, instead of a white background with black text. I have no idea how this code could be changing the color. Could anyone provide some info?

Comment: where in this code you set a layout or color for text? Maybe you should get us some more code?

Comment: That's my point. There's no code changing the colors at all, but they do change. I'm hoping maybe someone knew of some small idiosyncrasies that causes it.

Comment: what I see in this code: you creating a new view in the dialog, setting it onto the whole dialog, and that's all. Why, judjing by this code you thinking, that background should be white, and the text should be black?

Comment: All of my other layouts have a white background. This is the only one that is different. Also, in xml editor, it shows white with black text too!

Comment: Maybe in your other layouts you set light themes, and in this dialog default theme is black?

Comment: I just manually set the colors, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
Dialog d = adb.setView(new View(this)).create();
```

you ceate a new `View` which defaults to black background.

Then you use this view attributes everywhere:

```
lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

**Solution:**

After creating the new view, set the background:

```
View view = new View(this);
view.setBackgroundColor(...);
Dialog d = adb.setView(view).create();
```

Regards.